# MATLAB - split table into individual column arrays by their underlying data type?

Tags: matlab

In the example:

```
load hospital
T = dataset2table(hospital)
```

I converted to a table because I thought maybe it would be easier to work with. But I don't really care if the approach in the answer works with a dataset or table. I want to take each column, so "LastName","Sex", etc., get its underlying data type, and create a new variable for each of those columns. Is there a way to accomplish this without iterating through the table (i.e. a built-in function)? At least if I cannot convert to its underlying type, can I get them split into individual cell arrays?

The end result would have variables in the workspace as such:

LastName

Sex

Age

Weight

Smoker

BloodPressure

Trials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with a table, if you want to automatically generate the variables `LastName`, `Sex`, `Age` etc. you can:

- get the names of the variables: they are stored in the `Properties.VariableNames` property of the table
- then identify they number as the length of the varaible list
- loop through the table columns (the varaibles) to access to the data

The problem consists now in the creation of the names of the single varaibles in which to store the data in the workspace.

You can solve this problem by storing the data in a `struct` which allows dynamically generate the name of the fields.

You can, therefore, generate the names of the fields after the names of the variables in the table.

A possible implementation of the proposed approach colud be:

```
% Load the data
load hospital
% Convert dataset to table
T = dataset2table(hospital)
% Get the name of the varaibles
var_names=T.Properties.VariableNames
% Identify the number of varaibles (to be used in the next loop)
n_var=length(var_names)
% Store the data in a struct
% Get the name of the rows
hospital_data.row_names=T.Properties.RowNames;
% Loop over the variables
% Create dynamically the names of the fields of the struct after the name
% of the variables
for i=1:n_var
   hospital_data.(var_names{i})=T{:,i}
end
```

This generate a `struct` named `hospital_data` whose fields are:

```
hospital_data = 

        row_names: {100x1 cell}
         LastName: {100x1 cell}
              Sex: [100x1 nominal]
              Age: [100x1 double]
           Weight: [100x1 double]
           Smoker: [100x1 logical]
    BloodPressure: [100x2 double]
           Trials: {100x1 cell}
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Answer (score 0):

I think the functions `findgroups` and/or `splitapply` might help you!

Here's a link where you can check how they work:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/split-table-data-variables-and-apply-functions.html